# Select specific value from a dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Problem:
my dataframe shows forward contract settlements on a daily basis.  I want to create a column that returns all the January values.  So in November, M0 is November contract and I want to return M2, which is the January contract, then in December I would return M1.  The normal code for for doing this would be:

```
df['Jan'] = df.loc[(df.Month==12), ['M12]]
```

This only works for one value of the month though and I want to loop through the values in the Month column of the dataframe to pull the right 'Mx' column for the given month and have a single column with values for January.

I have tried various loops but continually get errors.  The latest I have below with the dataframe:

DataFrame

[image: Dataframe]

Code

[image: Code]

Error Message

[image: Error message]

Any help appreciated, I have googled all day.  Happy to hear any better ways of doing this

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please include any relevant information [as text directly into your question](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help), do not link or embed external images of source code or data. Images make it difficult to efficiently assist you as they cannot be copied and offer poor usability as they cannot be searched. See: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/15497888)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the whole dataframe and then access the columns within your function.
Try this.

```
def create_jan(x):
    if x['Month']== 11:
        return x['M1']
    elif x['month']==12:
        return x['M2']
    else:
        return 0


df['jan']= df.apply(create_jan, axis = 1)
```

Comment: This gives me a KeyErrror: 'Month'

Comment: i think that means the column 'Month' does not exist in the df, but it clearly does.

Comment: oh my bad, i missed out the axis = 1. by default axis  checks the axis = 0

Comment: Thanks - adding the axis=1 helped.  I really should have thought of that myself!  I stil;l get an error because I have too many indexers, but i need to try to solve that myself before wasting any more of your time.

Comment: I am getting   IndexingError: Too many indexers.  it is coming in line 3 of the code: return x.loc['Month', 'M1']

Comment: hmmm, try--->  return x.loc[:,'M1']

Comment: I think I have solved it, just by simplifying the return.  - so instead of return x.loc['Month', 'M1']   ; just having return x['M1]  seems to work.   is there any reason this would throw an issue down the line?

Comment: happy to mark it as the answer, how?  sorry, i am new to stackoverflow.  And thanks for all the help

Comment: great thanks  you can check this https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers